# Does "findOne" and "find" in MongoDB loop through the collection?

Tags: mongodb

Supposed I have a collection named dog. I want to find the document that has breed "German Shepherd". Somehow the document that contains "German Shepherd" in its "breed" field is the last one inserted, which means the document is at the end of the collection.

If I do

```
db.Dog.findOne({name: "German Sheperd"})
```

or

```
db.Dog.findOne({name: "German Sheperd"})
```

Assume I have not indexed any field, does it iterate through each document until the document that contains "German Sheperd", which is the last document, is foundd?

Is it same like the following for loop in JavaScript?

```
function findGermanShepard(dogs){
    for (let i=0; i<dogs.length; i++){
          const dog = dogs[i];
          if(dog.name == "German Sheperd"){
               return dog       
           } 
    }
   return null;
}
```

If I have 1 million documents in a collection like that, how long does it take to find a document based on a value of a field or a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the query `EXPLAIN` plan, to determine how the matching documents are searched for, like this:

```
db.Dog.explain().findOne({name: "German Sheperd"})
```

You can also provide an argument to the `explain` function, to determine its verbosity, like this:

```
db.Dog.explain('executionStats').findOne({name: "German Sheperd"})
```

Normally, if you don't have any indexes, you will see a stage named `COLLSCAN`, which refers to a collection scan, which means each and every document was looked up until a match is found.

Read more about the explain function [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/).

Comment: If I index the fields, will it still do a full scan?

Comment: Nope, if you create an index on the `name` field, you will get a stage `IXSCAN`, which means index scan, which is not a full scan